# django css design checkbox too small

Tags: css, django, django-templates

I have downloaded a design from the internet but the checkbox are too small. I don't have much time so can someone tell me how to overwrite the setting in the css file. Nothing seems to work.

the django template is as follows:

```
<form class="site-form" action="{% url 'doc_aide:the_doc_aide' pk=patient.id %}" method="post"
        enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <header class="first major">
            <h2 class="icon fa-file-alt">Doctors Notes</h2>
        </header>
        
        {{ formset.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Write Prescription">
    </form>
```

the css file is rather I can't add but I can ensure you that

input[type=checkbox] is nowhere to be found and if I add a new design it doesn't change anything.

How can I find out where that particular code is so I can change it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The form is populated as HTML into your template. To change the styling you need to apply CSS as static file.

**Template**

```
# Include the static file into the template
{% load static %}
<link href="{% static 'css/your_css_file.css' %}" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

<form class="site-form" action="{% url 'doc_aide:the_doc_aide' pk=patient.id %}" method="post"
        enctype='multipart/form-data'>
        {% csrf_token %}

        <header class="first major">
            <h2 class="icon fa-file-alt">Doctors Notes</h2>
        </header>
        
        # Add a container to your form
        <div id="form-container">

        {{ formset.as_p }}
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-default" value="Write Prescription">

        </div>
    </form>
```

Wrap your form in a div-container and apply CSS:

**CSS**

```
#form-container input {
    height: 5vh;
    width: 5vw;
    etc.
}

// or without container
.btn {
   your styling: here;
}
```

**Settings.py**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'static')]
```

Answer (score 1):

Where your form is defined. Add the style attribute in the field constructor.

For example:

**forms.py**

```py
myfield = forms.BooleanField(widget=forms.CheckBoxInput(attrs={'class' : 'zoomedCheckbox'}))
```

**<your_css_file>.css**

```css
.zoomedCheckbox {
    zoom: 1.5;
```

`zoom` property is a css trick to change the size of the checkbox by scale.

**Include in template**

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/your_css_file.css' %}">
```

Comment: Thank you that is good but I wanted a css solution.

Comment: Updated answer for css.