# How to change file browser button to image button by useing forms design in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I can create the following form:[image]

### I'm thinking when I click on the image like this:

[image]

Comment: See a prior answer to this from me here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62510715/django-css-design-checkbox-too-small/62511281#62511281

Answer (score 0):

You cannot apply CSS to the file upload button, but you can do the following:

- Create another div with the image in it.
- Give an id to your file upload button, then hide it with CSS (`visibility : hidden;`)
- Add an `onClick` event to the image div that will trigger a function that clicks on the original file upload button

Then, when you click the image, you'll get the pop-up for selecting your file. There's a tutorial here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3PDgtliezo